# shift bottom-border up in css

Tags: css, border

How can I push the bottom margin up with about 5 pixels using css?

[Here](http://jsbin.com/umeniz/1/edit) is the example about what I want to achieve:

[image: push up border]

Comment: can you please show us `HTML` and `CSS` Code that you have tried..?

Comment: I have tired negative margin/padding

Comment: but not set line height to samller, but that was the solution. http://jsbin.com/umeniz/2/

Comment: have you considered using an underline for this rather than a border?

Comment: @Spudley Yes, but that's not the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although you can do using `line-height`, it might screw up the next lines. So I suggest this:

```
h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #FF6A00;
  /* proposing line height + padding */
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Ah, okay, make it `margin-bottom`. :)

Comment: @catto It's more than 6 years old and it may not be relevant to the current situation.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with `line-height:`css rule.

set `line-height: 18px;` and that will do this trick.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qaYqR/) which uses padding.

```
padding-bottom: 5px;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with *underlining*. Like this:

```
h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 0;
  color: #FF6A00;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

h1 span {
  color: #000;
}
```

And then just put the text in `h1` inside a `span`:

```
<h1><span>Szavazás az új domain-ról</span></h1>
```

See this [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8KPxB/).